# JavaFX - Child count changed event

Tags: java, javafx

How can I run a method after the number of children in a specific element has changed?

It should function similarly to the example below which runs a method after the text property of a specific element changes.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller
{
    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        textArea.textProperty().addListener(e -> onTextPropertyChanged());
    }

    private void onTextPropertyChanged()
    {
        System.out.println("cabbage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableList`s allow you to add a `InvalidationListener`:

```
final ObservableList<Node> children = pane.getChildren();

InvalidationListener listener = new InvalidationListener() {

    private int size = children.size();

    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable o) {
        int newSize = children.size();
        if (size != newSize) { // prevent triggering if the size did not change
            size = newSize;
            // TODO: add some logic
        }
    }

};
children.addListener(listener);
```

Comment: re-inventing the wheel again ;) registering an InvalidationListener and keep track of the list size and react only if really changed is far too lowl-level for my liking. Depending on concrete use-case we could use higher-level api, that is either a Bindings.size(children) or wrap the children into a listProperty which provides a sizeProperty.